# FizzBuzz with a for loop switch statement

Tags: javascript

I have recently been following a Javascript course on CodeCademy and have got through Switch Statements and For Loops, I then tried to create a FizzBuzz game that prints to the console using a combination of the two. I can not figure out what I have done wrong.

I have tried removing the variables using their plain text counterparts and still achieved nothing. I don't even get any errors.

```
let fizzCalc = (i % 3 === 0);
let buzzCalc = (i % 5 === 0);

for ( var i = 0; i >= 100; i++) {
  switch(true) {
    case fizzCalc:
      console.log('Fizz');
      break;
    case buzzCalc:
      console.log('Buzz');
      break;
    case fizzCalc && buzzCalc:
      console.log('FizzBuzz');
      break;
    default: 
      console.log(i);
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo: `i <= 100`. Also, you will need to reorder the `&&` case to be first, and move the `fizzCalc` and `buzzCalc` into the loop.

Comment: `fizzCalc` and `buzzCalc` do not have a reference to `i` at the time they execute.

Comment: [switch - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: Not trying to be offensive, but there are *multiple* problems with this code that reflect a lack of basic understanding of programming (how/when/if variables are updated, how they are declared, how to count from 1-100 in a programming language, how scope works, etc). Work through some tutorials/books/whathaveyou before trying to create something from scratch (or cobbling together code from the interwebs).

Comment: @JaredSmith no offense taken, I can see this question wasn't very well researched or worded. I am sorry.

Comment: @LiamNugent its all good. Be sure to come back when you have a little more tutorial-working-through experience under your belt.

Comment: Your code example is great and your wording is fine. The only thing missing IMO is the exact problem you encountered. You should be getting an error message of some sort. You can post this in your question in order to give us a little more information about what you need help with.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am using CodeCademys built-in Javascript executer and it returns no error. I will look at using better software like brackets.

Comment: I suggest you read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. These tools might not have been terrible helpful in this particular case, but they are very important ones for you to learn to use as you learn how to code.

Comment: @LiamNugent As for errors, you should open your browser's console to see if there are any there. In Chrome, press Ctrl-Shift-I (that's an upper case eye) and click on the Console tab. You should definitely take some time to learn about all of the tools in this window. They are called the Chrome Developer Tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at these two lines of code:

```
let fizzCalc = (i % 3 === 0);
let buzzCalc = (i % 5 === 0);
```

You probably get an error here that `i` is undefined. The thing to keep in mind is that these formulas are all evaluated immediately. They aren't saved to evaluate them when you use the names `fizzCalc` and `buzzCalc` at a later time.

To fix the problem, you can move these two lines into your `for` loop:

```
for ( var i = 0; i >= 100; i++) {
    let fizzCalc = (i % 3 === 0);
    let buzzCalc = (i % 5 === 0);
    // ...
}
```

But now you will find that the loop never runs. This is because you have typed `>=` when you mean `<=`. So one more change should fix the problem:

```
for ( var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    let fizzCalc = (i % 3 === 0);
    let buzzCalc = (i % 5 === 0);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the things you need to do to fix this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) { // fixed loop to be less than

  let fizzCalc = (i % 3 === 0); // moved vars inside loop to give access to i
  let buzzCalc = (i % 5 === 0);

  switch (true) {
    case fizzCalc && buzzCalc: // moved this case up so it matches first 
      console.log('FizzBuzz');
      break;
    case fizzCalc:
      console.log('Fizz');
      break;
    case buzzCalc:
      console.log('Buzz');
      break;

    default:
      console.log(i);
      break;
  }
}
```